# how to add minutes to datetime field then select all that matches in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, datetime, mysqli

I have a datetime field called "active_date" . I would like to add 10 minutes to the active_date and select those currenttime > active date + 10 mins.

I have tried the following statements but it's not working.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM records WHERE reposted = 1 AND DATEADD(minute, 10, active_date);";

$sql = "SELECT * FROM records WHERE reposted = 0 AND currentdate > DATEADD(minute, 10, active_date);";
```

error:

> Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result

Comment: The keyword `AS` is for selected column and the tables, not in the WHERE section. The WHERE section is only for conditions nonsensical. Example: `SELECT foo AS bar FROM hello AS world`, which makes `DATEADD(minute, 10, active_date) AS DateAdd`. Please share your _all_ relevant code and look into [mysqli_error](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php)

Comment: thx very much for explaining @MagnusEriksson I removed the AS DateAdd and tried I again i still get the same error

Comment: Like I said, the WHERE part is for _conditions_ (filter down the result). You actually need to compare it to something. `DATEADD(minute, 10, active_date)` by itself isn't a condition. You need to compare it to something. I would recommend going through some basic SQL tutorial.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson please see my second statement I have compared with the "active_date". The reason I do this way is because I don't have a exact active_date. so the "active_date" is different for each rows depends and when it was activated. I just need to add 10 minutes to whatever the "active_date" is in the column and then select those are "active_date" > "active_date + 10 mins"

Comment: You still need to share _all_ your relevant code (like the code that actually gives you the error), example data and the expected output. Also, read the manual: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add

Comment: You realize of course that the active_date can never be greater than 10 minutes after the active_date.  Perhaps you should think about what you are looking to achieve.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson sorry I meant to compare it with the current time.

Comment: @DanBracuk yes you are right I was meaning to compare with current time, sorry for causing the confusion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax in MySQL uses `interval`, not `dateadd()` (at least with your syntax).  Your question doesn't make that much sense, unless I interpret "actual active date" as the current date time:

```
SELECT *
FROM records
WHERE reposted = 1 AND now() > active_date + interval 10 minute;
```

Comment: Thx so much @Gordon Linoff , yes I meant compare it with the current time, got myself confused when asking the question >< sorry